# Draw on Image in Java/Spring/JSP

Tags: java, image, spring, jsp, draw

i have an image implemented with `<img src=""/>` on a JSP Site.
Now I want to give the user the possibility to draw on that image (just one color and just a pencil) and upload this changed image to me.
How can I draw on an image?

We are using Spring Forms and the image is a CommonsMultipartFile.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Use an applet.  *"Kind Regards DonMarco"* Please leave out such noise in future.

Comment: Use javascript/Jquery plugins.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that politeness is unwanted.
Using Javascript/JQuery was my idea too, thanks, just don't know how!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a Image page is `"image.jsp"` and you have to write all the logic(action module) in `Image.java`(where the actual image will be drawn)"

<1> Create your image

```
public void drawImage(Graphics g){
 g.drawImage(image,x,y,null);
}
```

then for user in another class "UserImage.java"

<2> If you are using javax.swing.JPanel then you can add to load your picture

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("path-to-image-file"));
...
...
JColorChooser jColorChooser = new JColorChooser(your_image_file_name.getForeground());
```

<3> You can write down your own code for selecting pencil or pen

```
public Image image = new Image("Give_the_path_of_the file","x_parameter","y_parameter");
public void changeImage(Graphics g){
 g.drawImage(g)}
```

Your code will be according to user specificaton + it will be dynamic implementation

Here you should have to handle UserImage upload location.

Comment: Hi, thanks... that is already quiet near, but I am not using swing, since I have a web-service. And the tricky questions is:
how do I draw ON an existing picture and save this drawing on this picture as a new picture. All in a HTML / JSP Site.